# Getting insufficient access rights on cross-reference id when deploying Analytics Dataset components

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, metadata, einstein-analytics, analytics

Just created a scratch org and now attempting to deploy an entire wave folder, with one app, multiple datasets, and one dashboard.

None of the Analytics Dataset metadata components want to deploy and throw the same error "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id".
The scratch org user already has the "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" perm set.

I am thinking it must be some access to the objects or fields referenced in the dataset, but how is it possible, since the scratch org user has view all/modify all?

Any help is much appreciated. :)

EDIT: Now getting the error through the UI when I attempt to change the APP of the dataset to another app (and I have full access rights to it!) [image]

Comment: Does the user running the deployments have the Manage CRM Analytics permission set assigned as well? I've seen this impact deployments in the past.

Comment: Hey @CallumMacErlich! Yes, I have the following perm sets
CRM Analytics Platform Admin
CRM Analytics Plus Admin
CRM Analytics Template Administration Included
Service Analytics Admin
Contact Center Admin

So, quick update. I've managed to fine tune what the error is trying to do. It's trying to change the APP which a dataset is using. So I've tried to change the App of the dataset through the UI and get the same error (insufficient  rights..). I've seen this https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386880&type=1 but I am not sure it applies to me? I dont understand it..

Comment: That is a really useful find. Out of curiosity then, are you modifying a pre-built app or is it one that you've created entirely from scratch?

Comment: Yep, attempting to deploy the templated app that comes with service cloud voice.

Comment: @Vio did u manage to solve the deployment errors? pls do share your findings

Comment: @compski Yes, sure. 
So essentially, one cannot deploy a templated app because the metadata API deployment sequence differs from the Analytics App creation sequence.

So we had to implement a post-scractch creation step before we deploy the entire repo, including the Templated Analytics App.

So here are the steps for one app after a scratch org is created:

Comment: Continued: 
1. Navigate to Analytics App
2. Click "Create App". Select "Create Blank App". Click Continue. Name it: "MyTemplatedAnalyticsApp"
3. In the app, create Dataset. Select from CSV. Use dummy-csv.csv file. (this can have just one row and blank data). Click "Next. Name the dataset "MyDatasetFromTemplatedApp". Click "Next".
4. Once process is finished you can now push entire force-app folder. This will overwrite the App you created with correct app from salesforce project folder.

So we're essentially creating a dummy app and dataset, for the metadata API to simply replace/rename